How to remove flicker in ScrollView of changing height when using .defaultScrollAnchor(...) in SwiftUI
I am using a ScrollView with a .defaultScrollAnchor(.bottom) (see code below). When the ScrollView is not filled with content, i.e. the content height inside is smaller than the ScrollView height, and the ScrollView changes its height, the content "flickers" (see video) from top to bottom, when it should just stay at the top.

            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack(spacing: 10) {
                    ForEach(viewModel.messageItems, id: \.id) { messageItem in
                        Text(messageItem.text ?? "n")
                    }
                }.background(.green)
            }
            .background(.red)
            .defaultScrollAnchor(.bottom)
            // .scrollTargetLayout(isEnabled: true) <- tried this, changes nothing

